# Datagridview changes content on repaint while binding source is suspended

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, bindingsource

In a winforms project I have a datagridview which add rows periodically. New rows must show up at the top, so we use

```
bindingSource.Insert(0,item);
```

This works fine so far. New rows are added to the top of the table. Now, the user needs to have the ability to pause the updating to examine the table, then resume updating later. So to pause it, I use:

```
bindingSource.RaiseListChangedEvents = false;
```

And to resume:

```
bindingSource.RaiseListChangedEvents = true;
bindingSource.ResetBindings(false);
```

Which has the desired effect. The table does not update while suspended, and resumes as expected. While it is suspended, new rows are continually being added to the bindingsource.

What goes wrong is when the table is clicked or repainted - the cells change value. It appears that the bound data is redrawn with the table, even though RaiseListChangedEvents is false. I pointed out the Insert method above, because this issue does not occur if I use bindingSource.Add().

Any way around this?

Comment: Suspending notifications is not enough. `DataGridView` retrieves the data needed for painting from the data source **by index**. You need to suspend adding new items to the binding source (for instance, buffer them in some outside list and flush the buffer when resuming the update).

Comment: I was afraid of that

Comment: Yeah :( Shouldn't be a big deal though.